# Performance of arcpy.Exists() in SQL Server enterprise gdb environment

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, sql-server

While iterating on a list containing table names,
I used arcpy.Exists() to check if a table/featureclass exists.
This action is very time consuming.
I've ended up using a database approach `select count(*) from 'tablename'` 
and checked the query result to check if a table exists, which works very fast.
I even tried using a readonly user/administrative user for arcpy.Exists(), still received the same performance problem.
My questions:
1. Does anyone knows why arcpy.Exists() is so slow vs SQL server (it is much faster in SDE)?
2. Any other ideas for workarounds? my list contains 400  names, I'd rather use arcpy on creating multiple db queries.

Comment: SDE no longer exists, and you're already using all that remains of that which used to be ArcSDE. You might try using arcpyListFeatureClasses then using list operators (though you'll need to handle database and schema). Also possible is a dictionary query in SQL, though this RDBMS-dependent.

Comment: The list approach might be more efficient than multiple queries - thanks :) [you can add an answer]. The part about SDE : we have an old server that still non SQL server (old arcSDE) and arcpy.Exists() works much faster on it...

Comment: You seem to be using "SDE" as a database reference, but "old ArcSDE"  supported Oracle, Informix, DB2, SQL-Server, and PostgreSQL, and before that Sybase, so it's not clear which one was faster.

Comment: @Vince ArcSDE SQL-Server/MS-SQL10 /ArcGIS 9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the interesting quirks of many SQL client APIs is the lack of a "table exists" function.  Many implementations of an "exists" are really a low-level "describe", which returns a "does not exist" error if the table doesn't exist, and populates metadata if it does.  The side effect of this is that an "exists" test is often quite slow, because if it succeeds, then it has to clean up something that cost effort to create.

The function in ArcPy which tests for table existence (`arcpy.Exists()`) has the overhead of verifying the connection string, then describing the table and cleaning up. By comparison, the `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` function has connection overhead, and then requests the list of tables, and then needs to either consult the geodatabase metadata or describe each table in turn to see if it has a geometry column, and potentially needs to describe it anyway, to see if anything has changed, or if unsupported columns are present, so this isn't an intrinsically fast process either.
So then the issue is which is faster, compiling a list of valid tables or describing all the tables up front, then sifting through the result for potential matches (the answer for which could vary by database implementation, number of tables, and number of columns).

There is another mechanism, which is to execute an RDBMS-dependent query against the system catalog via the `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute()` function, and ***assume*** that the table is valid if the database reports that it exists.

Now, I don't have a MS SQL Server instance handy (new laptop, no need), but I can perform some timing tests with PostgreSQL. The experiment I propose is as follows:

- Create 65 random-named tables in the form 'tableNN' with six columns, one of which is an identity (ID) column, and another geometry.
- Measure the performance of using `arcpy.Exists` on tables 00 through 99 (tracking the timing for both existing and non-existing tables)
- Measure the performance of using `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses` to retrieve all tables as the owner, then test against this list to determine existance
- Measure the performance of using `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute` to retrieve a table list, then test existance with this list as well
- Repeat the above with tables of just two columns, and tables with forty columns

And the results for six, two, and forty columns are:

```
       Tot (all) = 6.1800
      Mean (all) = 0.0618
      Mean (exi) = 0.0920
      Mean (dne) = 0.0057
    List elapsed = 3.4900
      List total = 3.4900 (65 found)
     SQL elapsed = 0.0200
       SQL total = 0.0200 (65 found)
----------
       Tot (all) = 5.6300
      Mean (all) = 0.0563
      Mean (exi) = 0.0832
      Mean (dne) = 0.0063
    List elapsed = 2.6800
      List total = 2.6800 (65 found)
     SQL elapsed = 0.0100
       SQL total = 0.0100 (65 found)
----------
       Tot (all) = 6.5800
      Mean (all) = 0.0658
      Mean (exi) = 0.0986
      Mean (dne) = 0.0049
    List elapsed = 3.3600
      List total = 3.3600 (65 found)
     SQL elapsed = 0.0100
       SQL total = 0.0100 (65 found)
```

So it seems as if, anecdotally, my above assertions are borne out:

- The `Exists` cascade takes 5.63-6.58 seconds
- Testing for non-existent tables is significantly (order of magnitude) 
  faster than existing ones
- Wider tables take longer to test than skinnier ones
- Using `ListFeatureClasses` takes 2.68-3.49 seconds (roughly half of `Exists`)
- Using the `information_schema` query in PostgreSQL takes 10-20 **milliseconds**

Also somewhat interesting: Converting the list to a dictionary and then searching the dictionary 100 times took no measureable time (Windows box, so sub-millisecond)

Now obviously, you'd need to tweak the actual SQL for SQL Server, but I'll provide the Python here for reference*:

```
import math
import os
import random
from datetime import datetime

print("Importing arcpy...")
import arcpy

# -----------------------------------
def findTables(names,schema,fmt,count):
    found = []
    d = {}
    for name in names:
        parts = name.split('.')
        d[parts[2]] = name
    for i in range(count):
        table = fmt.format(i)
        if (table in d):
            found.append(table)
    return found
# -----------------------------------

verbose=False
keep=65
fudge=keep-12
total=100
schema=""
geomcol="geom"
tableFmt="xxtmp_table{:02d}"
random.seed(42)

dropStatement   = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {:s}{:s}"

createStatement6 = """CREATE TABLE {:s}{:s} (
  objectid        serial          NOT NULL,
  col1            smallint            NULL,
  col2            integer             NULL,
  col3            real                NULL,
  col4            varchar(20)         NULL,
  {:<12s}    geometry            NULL,
  CONSTRAINT {:s}_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_{:s} CHECK (st_srid({:s}) = 4326)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
)"""

createStatement2 = """CREATE TABLE {:s}{:s} (
  objectid        serial          NOT NULL,
  {:<12s}    geometry            NULL,
  CONSTRAINT {:s}_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_{:s} CHECK (st_srid({:s}) = 4326)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
)"""

createStatement40 = """CREATE TABLE {:s}{:s} (
  objectid        serial          NOT NULL,
  col1            smallint            NULL,
  col2            integer             NULL,
  col3            real                NULL,
  col4            varchar(20)         NULL,
  col5            varchar(20)         NULL,
  col6            smallint            NULL,
  col7            integer             NULL,
  col8            real                NULL,
  col9            varchar(20)         NULL,
  col10           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col11           smallint            NULL,
  col12           integer             NULL,
  col13           real                NULL,
  col14           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col15           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col16           smallint            NULL,
  col17           integer             NULL,
  col18           real                NULL,
  col19           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col20           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col21           smallint            NULL,
  col22           integer             NULL,
  col23           real                NULL,
  col24           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col25           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col26           smallint            NULL,
  col27           integer             NULL,
  col28           real                NULL,
  col29           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col30           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col31           smallint            NULL,
  col32           integer             NULL,
  col33           real                NULL,
  col34           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col35           varchar(20)         NULL,
  col36           smallint            NULL,
  col37           integer             NULL,
  col38           real                NULL,
  {:<12s}    geometry            NULL,
  CONSTRAINT {:s}_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_{:s} CHECK (st_srid({:s}) = 4326)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
)"""

listStatement="""SELECT (table_catalog ||'.' || table_schema || '.' || table_name)::varchar(100) as name
FROM    information_schema.tables
WHERE   table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND   table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')"""

conn = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"bench.sde")
cursor = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(conn)

for createStatement in [createStatement6, createStatement2, createStatement40]:
    count = 0
    print '----------'
    # .. (re)Create tables
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    created=[]
    for i in range(total):
        if (math.floor(random.random() * 100) < fudge or (total - i) < (total - keep)):
            table = tableFmt.format(i)

            sql = dropStatement.format(schema,table)
            if (verbose): print("{:s};".format(sql))
            cursor.execute(sql)

            sql = createStatement.format(schema,table,geomcol,table,geomcol,geomcol)
            if (verbose): print("{:s};\n".format(sql))
            cursor.execute(sql)

            created.append(table)
            count += 1
            if (count >= keep): break

    elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
    #print("{:>16s} = {:.4f} secs".format("Prep",elapsed))

    # .. Measure Exists

    allSum = 0.0
    exiSum = 0.0
    dneSum = 0.0
    for i in range(total):
        table = tableFmt.format(i)
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        doesExist = arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(conn,"{:s}{:s}".format(schema,table)))
        elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
        allSum += elapsed
        if (doesExist):
            exiSum += elapsed
        else:
            dneSum += elapsed
        if (verbose): print("{:s} ({:s})".format(table,"Y" if doesExist else "N"))

    print("{:>16s} = {:.4f}".format("Tot (all)",allSum))
    print("{:>16s} = {:.4f}".format("Mean (all)",allSum / float(total)))
    print("{:>16s} = {:.4f}".format("Mean (exi)",exiSum / float(keep)))
    print("{:>16s} = {:.4f}".format("Mean (dne)",dneSum / float(total-keep)))

    # .. Measure ListFC

    arcpy.env.workspace = conn
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    allTables = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()

    print("{:>16s} = {:.4f}".format("List elapsed",elapsed))
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    found = findTables(allTables,schema,tableFmt,total)
    elapsed += (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
    print("{:>16s} = {:.4f} ({:d} found)".format("List total",elapsed,len(found)))

    # .. Measure SQL

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    sql = listStatement
    allTables = [row[0] for row in cursor.execute(sql)]
    elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()

    print("{:>16s} = {:.4f}".format("SQL elapsed",elapsed))
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    found = findTables(allTables,schema,tableFmt,total)
    elapsed += (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
    print("{:>16s} = {:.4f} ({:d} found)".format("SQL total",elapsed,len(found)))

    # .. Cleanup

    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    for table in created:
        sql = dropStatement.format(schema,table)
        if (verbose): print("{:s};".format(sql))
        cursor.execute(sql)
    elapsed = (datetime.datetime.now() - start).total_seconds()
    #print("{:>16s} = {:.4f} secs".format("Cleanup",elapsed))

cursor = None

#EOF
```

*Note: hack job; took way longer than I wanted to make, so it's *as-is*.

---

Follow-up:  I used this technique in an application against a PostgreSQL database and ran into an issue with failure to detect views and materialized views.  Adding view support was as simple as changing the SQL that compiles the list to `UNION ALL` a query to information_schema.views:

```
  SELECT (table_schema || '.' || table_name)::varchar(255) as name
  FROM  information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
UNION ALL
  SELECT (table_schema || '.' || table_name)::varchar(255) as name
  FROM  information_schema.views
  WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
```

But for PostgreSQL, at least, materialized views are not published through `information_schema` (because `MATERIALIZED VIEW` is an extension), so for them I needed to append a PG-specific catalog query:

```
UNION ALL
  SELECT (schemaname || '.' || matviewname)::varchar(255) as name
  FROM  pg_matviews
```

Comment: Wow! I know comments are not meant to be a 'thank you' place, still wanted to point out that your answer is really thorough and interesting :)

Comment: I just added a test based on `"SELECT count(*) FROM {:s}{:s} WHERE 1 = 0".format(schema,table)`, just for grins, and it came in at 120-260 milliseconds, which is way better than `ListFeatureClasses` but still an order of magnitude off the `information_schema` query.  If your tables have rows, adding the "`WHERE 1 = 0`" is the canonical way to avoid the overhead of processing them.